# number input - always show spin buttons

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, `input[type=number]` spin buttons are shown only on hover.

[image: Chrome spin buttons]

This is the code I use:

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="999" />
```

Is there any way to always show spin buttons?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can target spin buttons using `::-webkit-inner/outer-spin-button` and than just set `opacity` to 1 (spins are always there, but in default they have `opacity: 0`).

Code:

```
<style>  

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}

</style>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="999">
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dk8fj/

Comment: Is there a cross-browser approach?

Comment: what about firefox and other browsers? It works only in chrome

Comment: In firefox and safari, its a default feature to show it always.

Comment: do you have the solution for mobile please ? i want to buil a web app.

Comment: It is worth noting that with iPad on Safari 12.1 that @Rathore25 comment is no longer true. Safari does not show input type number spinners.