# Is it possible to always show up/down arrows for input "number"?

Tags: html, css, input, webkit, shadow-dom

I want to always show up/down arrows for input "number" field. Is this possible? So far I haven't had any luck...
http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/qunbnL6u/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  

   -webkit-appearance: "Always Show Up/Down Arrows";

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number input - always show spin buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286506/number-input-always-show-spin-buttons)

Comment: Did you find the solution? It doesn't work in my case.

Comment: what browser are you using? it works in Chrome

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can achieve this (in Chrome at least) by using the Opacity property:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  

   opacity: 1;

}
```

As stated above, this will likely only work in Chrome. So be careful using this code in the wild without a fallback for other browsers.

Comment: as @NewBeeee said: In firefox and safari, its a default feature to show it always (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286506/number-input-always-show-spin-buttons)

Answer (score 20):

I tried this and it worked

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}

</style>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="999">
```

[Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286506/number-input-always-show-spin-buttons)

Comment: is it possible to display the up and down number range option for input type="text". Because I am applying a regex pattern validation as: Validators.pattern(/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$/), to restrict the user to enter values between 1 to 999 only. And I am using input as text as this pattern is not working for input type=number, as the same pattern does allow the user to type 01 0999 etc values which start with 0, which is not correct, though this number type has the feature of min & max which displays up/down arrows by default.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and it's working

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the same appearance across different browsers you may be forced to use a plugin/widget or build one yourself, the main browsers all seem to implement number spinners differently.

Try [jQuery UI's spinner widget](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) it offers a lot more versatility when it comes to styling.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/44431mbt/)**

```
<p>
    <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
    <input id="spinner" name="value" />
</p>

$("#spinner").spinner();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the every browsers support, i just wanted to know if there was a css trick to allow them to always be viewable

Comment: My whole idea behind it was "degrade gracefully".. if browser doesn't support it will appear to be just a text box. . It they do they take on the appearance of the default number spinner, but not just on hover

Comment: Problem with JQuery UI is it has lots of conflicts with bootstrap. So if you are using bootstrap in your project then you will be in trouble

Answer (score 1):

For me only additional CSS settings helps:

```
<style>
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button 
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, 
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```