# How to control the size of input type="number" arrow buttons

Tags: css, html

I'm implementing an input combo box of type="number".

I want to adjust the size of the up-arrow button and bottom-arrow button.

I think that these buttons are so small buttons that users may feel an inconvenient click motion.

I've been trying to fix this by Googling, investigating properties and selectors of this, but I couldn't get any methods, and I expect that this is because number box has been recently released tag of HTML5.

How Can I adjust this size? please give me any idea. please.

Regards,

[image]

```
<td>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="1" name="goodsnum" onChange = "qtyChanged();">
</td>
```

Comment: please paste the HTML of this button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can interact with arrows by css.

```css
input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
}

input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button {  
    width: 14px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" >
```

Comment: Unfortunately (at least on Chrome on macOS) the arrows themselves stay incredibly tiny

Comment: On Mac ElCapitan, Firefox(v54.0.1), the arrows are still very tiny.

Comment: Sometimes, after clicking the arrow and moving the mouse away, the input stays in focus but is no longer hovered so the buttons remain visible but revert to their small size. I added the focus selector to fix this.
`input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]:focus::-webkit-inner-spin-button`

Comment: Firefox doesn't support this pseudo-element selector and there are a bunch of issues on their bug tracker dating back *years* with arguments for/against.  It's a mess.

Comment: to show the buttons alwas (not on hover only) add `input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { opacity: 1 !important; }`

Comment: Thanks. To me, `height` works for Chrome, but `width` does not.

Comment: Firefox does not support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. 
I found it here: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ 
From this related question: [Increase the size of the down and up arrow on the number input, CSS, HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234393/increase-the-size-of-the-down-and-up-arrow-on-the-number-input-css-html)

```js
$( function() {
  var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();

  $( "#disable" ).on( "click", function() {
    if ( spinner.spinner( "option", "disabled" ) ) {
      spinner.spinner( "enable" );
    } else {
      spinner.spinner( "disable" );
    }
  });
  $( "#destroy" ).on( "click", function() {
    if ( spinner.spinner( "instance" ) ) {
      spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
    } else {
      spinner.spinner();
    }
  });
  $( "#getvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
  });
  $( "#setvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
    spinner.spinner( "value", 5 );
  });

  $( "button" ).button();
} );
```

```css
.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-spinner-button.ui-spinner-up {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-spinner-button.ui-spinner-down {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
</head>
 
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="value">
</p>
```

Comment: Try it out, tell me how it goes, and then make sure to mark it as correct if I have helped you :)

Comment: I'm sure IE can handle jQuery. If that's your question. Well depending on which IE version you have of course.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick comment. well,  mobile  too?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is a universal JavaScript library and if the browser is new enough and the jQuery library is imported and working on let's say desktop, it will also work on mobile :)

Comment: How can I get the  designed demo source codes in local link such as<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149535/discussion-between-ricky-dam-and-hsw4840).