# How to scale the heights numerical spinner (input type="number")

Tags: html, css, input

So I'm designing a website that requires a large spinner for number input and I made it quite tall with a large font (take this code as an EXAMPLE):

```
<input type="number" name="number" style="width: 100%; height: 110px; font-size: 100px;">
```

[image: large spinner]

And as you can see, the two spinner buttons on the side that increase and decrease the number are awkwardly small. As far as I can tell, there are no attributes to remedy this, but please someone tell me I'm wrong. Or at least, tell me how you would go about it. Create the spinner myself from scratch, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the size of input type="number" arrow buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166871/how-to-control-the-size-of-input-type-number-arrow-buttons)

Comment: I read tat question and a whole bunch of others and it seams everything sucks. I guess I'm going to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. 
http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

```js
$( function() {
  var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();

  $( "#disable" ).on( "click", function() {
    if ( spinner.spinner( "option", "disabled" ) ) {
      spinner.spinner( "enable" );
    } else {
      spinner.spinner( "disable" );
    }
  });
  $( "#destroy" ).on( "click", function() {
    if ( spinner.spinner( "instance" ) ) {
      spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
    } else {
      spinner.spinner();
    }
  });
  $( "#getvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
  });
  $( "#setvalue" ).on( "click", function() {
    spinner.spinner( "value", 5 );
  });

  $( "button" ).button();
} );
```

```css
.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-spinner-button.ui-spinner-up {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-spinner-button.ui-spinner-down {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
</head>
 
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="value">
</p>
```