# website form date type issue

Tags: php, input, types

```
 Reservation Date<br> <input style="height:40px;width:300px;" type="date"   name="date">
   <span class="error">*<?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Reservation Time<br>(Mon - Thur: 18:00 - 23:00 Fri - Sun: 12:00 - 00:00)<br> <input type="time" align="center" style="height:40px;width:300px;" name="time">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
```

[image]

> i am trying to make a form for a website. i used type date for the
>   date entry and made the box larger. however the arrows are very small
>   and do not take the whole box as shown in the image. does anyone know
>   how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to change the style of the arrow in the element. But you can hack a little bit around it. Check out this question. I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

[Making up down arrow of HTML's input number very bigger and cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598247/making-up-down-arrow-of-htmls-input-number-very-bigger-and-cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Class and use this

```
.myinputdate::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.myinputdate::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { 
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
```

This only work in WebKit browser.

Comment: Note that this will only work in Webkit based browsers.