# Input number in Angular Material Design?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

There is the standard input as:

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="Hours">
```

Is there something in Angular Material Design?

[image]

I use Angular latest version

I tried this, but it is just simple input:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput type="number" placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</md-input-container>
```

It should be  `< md-input-container input="number">`? `ot input type="number">` ?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview - Supported input types: number

Comment: yes they have, just set the type='number'. Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/1B06VtjfSpWXT7T98Lll?p=preview

Comment: are you trying to force users to only type numbers only or you want to use the type for error validation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In short, yes. You want < md-input-container > wrapper which supports the following input types

1. date
2. datetime-local
3. email
4. month
5. number
6. password
7. search
8. tel
9. text
10. time
11. url
12. week

For example

```
<md-input-container>
    <input
        mdInput
        type="number"
        id="myNumber"
    />
</md-input-container>
```

Checkout https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: Can share example, because it is not clear where to set property: `type="number" 
`

Comment: It should be  `< md-input-container input="number">`? `ot input type="number">` ?

Comment: It is simple input type="number" I can not style arrows in this case

Comment: How to style arrows (up, down) in CSS?

Comment: It is not perfect, I inserted "+", "." and "-".

Comment: The link makes no mention of `md-input-container `. `md-input-container ` is for AngularJS Material, not Angular Material.

Answer (score 17):

Use this for angular material number,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    type="number"
    class="form-control"
    matInput
    name="value"
    placeholder="Slab"
    (change)="xxx()"
    formControlName="value">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This answer is necessary since its the first result on Google if you are looking for `matInput number type`.

Answer (score 2):

`<md-input-container></md-input-container>` is not working anymore

This works fine.

```
<mat-label>Time</mat-label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" matInput name="time" placeholder="Time" change="xxx($event)" formControlName="time" required>
```

In .TS file, you can have the change event with `xxx (e) { console.log(e); }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field__input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
   /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066261/angular-material-15-does-not-have-time-or-datetime-picker-icon-for-selection-of/75067056#75067056 */
  -webkit-appearance: auto;
  appearance: auto;
  /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194631/is-it-possible-to-always-show-up-down-arrows-for-input-number/59555901#59555901 */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

To moderator: I have deleted my other duplicated answer.