# Angular material 15 does not have time or datetime picker icon for selection of time or date

Tags: angular, angular-material

When creating angular 15.0.4 project then added angular material from cli command. Steps to reproduce bug(angular 15.0.4)

1. ng new sample_project
2. ng add @angular/material (indigo-pink.css)
3. added MatFormField and MatInputModule in NgModule
   [My code in component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94l9r.png)
4. added code to html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="time">
</mat-form-field>
```

5. ng serve (does not show the clock icon to select time)
   [view image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atquj.png)

Here is the stackblitz sample app to reproduce bug
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwx3pq?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html

but when I remove mat-form-field and matInput in html just plain html element
(), the clock icon will show up.

I have tried in version 14, and everything works. The clock icon shows up with the same code and configurations.

Angular 15.0.4 result:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHRV.png)
Angular 14 result:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcy0.png)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: see this working : https://therichpost.com/angular-15-material-date-range-picker-working-demo/

Comment: the icon is about the navigator. if you want an icon, add it manually

Comment: There is no material time picker. There's [an issue tracking it](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648), but no implementation yet.

Comment: @Eliseo, Thank you for your response but I'm talking about time '<input type="time" />' the clickable icon on the right side does not appear

Comment: If you try to create an angular project in version 14 below, input type='time' clickable icon shows and word perfectly even inside mat-form-field

Comment: please refer pictures above

Comment: @CarloJuneCaimen It was good you added the pictures showing the difference. You could next time consider to make 2 working examples in Stackblitz, one for Material 14 and one for Material 15 to demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the time picker indicator is hidden by css in this version of the material library. See following style:

```
.mdc-text-field__input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

You can easily overwrite this behavior in the css of your component as follows:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field__input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: block;
}
```

If you want this behavior globally you will need to add it to your application stylesheet without the `:host` and `::ng-deep` selectors and an `important!` flag to suppress the default behavior.

```
.mdc-text-field__input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: block !important;
}
```

See screenshot from the developer console below with the relevant css marked in red.

[image]

See [this updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwx3pq-8wbbdv?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.css) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also have other solution by removing .mdc-text-field__input in AfterViewInit but anyway, I applied your solution, thanks master.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix>
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>access_time</mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

but if you want action on click use this;

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker">
   <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>access_time</mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm talking about time '<input type="time" />' the clickable icon on the right side does not appear