# HTML input type="number" butons on mobile

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to get the up/down arrows to appear next to an input element with type="number" in Chrome on android. I've added CSS to give them opacity=1 but they still don't show up. They appear fine on desktop.

Comment: Hey you can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194631/is-it-possible-to-always-show-up-down-arrows-for-input-number

Comment: as stated, I'm trying to get them to show on mobile. that answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;

}
```

Comment: that's the code I used to set their opacity, but they still don't show

Comment: are you able to inspect the element and see why it's not showing?

Comment: not on mobile unfortunatley, unless someone knows how to do that

Comment: it's easy if you are using safari and an iphone

Comment: as stated, I'm using chrome on android

Comment: ah yes my bad. there's probably a way though? google will know