# Increment arrows not showing up on form input

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a basic form input for a number. The form works. The field will not accept letters being type into it. But the increment arrows that usually show up for `type="number"` aren't showing up. What am I missing?

```
<div>
<input 
  type="number" 
  id="cost" 
  className="form-field" 
  placeholder="Cost"
  min="0"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={hats.cost}/>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this answer your question, [Show Up Down arrow in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194631/is-it-possible-to-always-show-up-down-arrows-for-input-number)

Comment: I put your code in codepen and it is working fine. It should be Interference with other library!  for example some css code that can remove arrow like: `::-webkit-outer-spin-button`.

Comment: No. I've tried input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
} but still no luck. I'm seeing that this could be a browser thing, but I'm using Chrome and I know I've done projects with them in Chrome before.

Comment: `<style>  

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}

</style>`

This will work with chrome atleat

Comment: @Vinoth.R I've seen that but it's just not working for me.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you try hovering over the input field?  (I know this question is absurd but just want to double check )

Comment: I did, yes. I've tried adding/eliminating the placeholder and step, too. I'm just so stumped because I've never had this happen.