# How to reset number input back to default behaviour in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a file where the following CSS is defined

```
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Now I wanted to target a specific target to undo the above. With FireFox I can simply do

```
.reset [type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: spinner-textfield;
}
```

But in Chrome, this doens't work

```
.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: spinner-textfield;
}
```

**FireFox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

```css
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.reset [type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: spinner-textfield;
}

.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: spinner-textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />

<div class="reset">
    <input type="number" />
</div>
```

How can I let the spinner buttons reappear in Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number input - always show spin buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286506/number-input-always-show-spin-buttons)

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa No, I don't want it to be visible all times.

Comment: From there you can modify the code to your desired end result, which makes this question a duplicate

Comment: Nope, see accepted anwser. Thats what I wanted, nothing to do with visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you're looking for is `inner-spin-button`, see snippet.

```css
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.reset [type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: spinner-textfield;
}

.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.reset input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />

<div class="reset">
    <input type="number" />
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, this value isn't present in the autocomplete of VS2015. So we were struggling and searching along time.

Comment: Np, another thing: Is there a reason you have to do it like this? Isn't it easier to bind the `-webkit-appearance: none;` to a classname?

Comment: Yeah we could do that, but its alot of work at the moment. Because alot of input fields exists.